# Why do MP3 thumbnails take so long to regenerate?

Tags: nautilus, mp3, thumbnails

I'm on 22.04 with Cinnamon but I have noticed this for a long time indeed with 20.04 and 18.04.
When I open Files (Nautilus) and navigate to a directory that contains MP3 files, the thumbnails take ages to regenerate. Well that they are generic thumbnails.
Has anyone else noticed this?
Can someone shed some light on it? I don't really expect a solution but it will be nice to know why, and if a solution is available.
[image: My_music]

Comment: You have .mp3 files, which contain audio, not any image that could generate thumbnails. Any thumbnail that are generated are actually downloaded from an album art cloud service. Cloud services usually want to limit the number of requests you are making. Someone can write an answer on how to change this limit at your own risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the album art to the actual files with `ffmpeg`.

```
ffmpeg -i "your_song.mp3" -i *png -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy "your_song_with_cover.mp3"
```

Add art to the entire directory:

```
for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i *png -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy out-"${f#./}" && mv out-"${f#./}" "$f"; done
```

---

**Here's a GUI you can use.**

- Adds artwork to a single file or all files in a folder.
- Accepts PNG & JPG.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

yad --title="MP3 Album Art" --window-icon="applications-multimedia" --borders="15" \
--form --separator=" " --item-separator=" " --text-align="center" --image-on-top --image="insert-image" --text="Choose: File or Folder\nImage: PNG or JPG" \
--field=File:LBL "" \
--field="":FL \
--field=Folder:LBL "" \
--field="":DIR "" \
--field=Artwork:LBL "" \
--field="":FL \
--field="Backup?":CHK \
> /tmp/entries

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

file_input=$(cat /tmp/entries | awk '{print $1}')
img_input=$(cat /tmp/entries | awk '{print $2}')
backup=$(cat /tmp/entries | awk '{print $3}')

if [[ $backup == TRUE ]]; then
    if [[ -d "$file_input" ]]; then
        cd "$file_input"
        mp3_files=$(find . -name "*.mp3")
        if [[ -n "$mp3_files" ]]; then
            tar cf "backup.tar" $mp3_files
        fi
    else
        cp "$file_input" "$file_input.bak"
    fi
fi

if [[ -n "$file_input" ]]; then
    if [[ ! -d "$file_input" ]]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$file_input" -i "$img_input" -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy "out-${file_input##*/}" && mv "out-${file_input##*/}" "$file_input"
    else
        for file in "$file_input"/*.mp3; do
            ffmpeg -i "$file" -i "$img_input" -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy "out-${file##*/}" && mv "out-${file##*/}" "$file"
        done
    fi
fi

rm /tmp/entries

exit 0
```

Save to: `add_artwork.sh`
Change mode: `chmod +x add_artwork.sh`
Run with: `./add_artwork.sh`

Comment: Okay I got it, I make my own thumbnails and attribute them to the mp3 files. I've done this once before but with the GUI.

Comment: I made this script with had a few years back for ID3 editing.  Here's the post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431638/7986904  Give me a second, I can update it to include album art.

Comment: @Raffles There's a simple GUI to make it simple.  Use `sudo apt-get install yad ffmpeg` for the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am going to try them, however I see there is a "Downvote Crusader" on the prowl here so I will likely delete my question. I have no time for the high and mighty downvote fraternity when a question is asked in all honesty. They hide behind their avatars and discourage participation.  We are here to help each other and I thank you for your assistance, I would mark it as the accepted answer since it has helped me understand a little more about Linux. I would first like to know from the downvote overlord which element of my question does not fit the Ask Ubuntu Bible?

Comment: That's why I still answer down voted questions. I'm just trying to help someone in need, screw 'em. You're talking about using Linux on an Ubuntu forum.  Umm.  Yeah, exactly.

Comment: @Raffles Accepting an answer will give you +2 reputation, exactly enough to offset the -2 from that one guy's downvote. Furthermore, deleting your answer will not help you avoid a question ban, and might even make the system more likely to issue one. If I were you, I would wait until at least a second downvote before I would delete a question